# Postgresql function for nested selects within an insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, procedural

I created a function abcd_insert() which inserts data into table abcd, which has 8 columns. The code inside the function looks similar to below :

```
BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO abcd

 VALUES 
      (
    x                 ,
    y                 ,
    select sum(count) from (select count(*) from a where a1 = x and a2 = y and a3 = 1 union all select count(*) from b where b1 = x and b2 = y and b3 = 1 ) as n1,
    select sum(count) from (select count(*) from a where a1 = x and a2 = y and a2 = 2 union all select count(*) from b where b1 = x and b2 = y and b3 = 2 ) as n2 ,
    select sum(count) from (select count(*) from a where a1 = x and a2 = y and a2 = 3 union all select count(*) from b where b1 = x and b2 = y and b3 = 3 ) as n3 ,
    select sum(count) from (select count(*) from a where a1 = x and a2 = y and a2 = 4 union all select count(*) from b where b1 = x and b2 = y and b3 = 4 ) as n4 ,
    select sum(count) from (select count(*) from a where a1 = x and a2 = y and a2 = 5 union all select count(*) from b where b1 = x and b2 = y and b3 = 5 ) as n5 ,
    SELECT sum(q1) from
    (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as q1 FROM p1 where p11 = x and p12 = y union all
    SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as q1 FROM p2 where p21 = x and p22 = y )  as q1
  ); 
END;
```

'x' and 'y' are my input parameters whose values will be passed to the function abcd_insert(). a,b,p1 and p2 are tables within the same schema.
When I pass 'x' and 'y' to the function at run time, it throws error.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You have 2 subqueries here. One is missing alias.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the column, not only the derived table:

```
SELECT SUM(foo) as foo
FROM ((SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as foo FROM a.a1 where p1=100) UNION ALL
      . . .
     ) x
```

Comment: Or vice versa: the OP had named the column, but not the derived table. The `x` is the part they need (`as bar` might be a clearer example).